# Flutter Gridview in Column. What's solution..?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem with gridview and column. In this case, i want put an image in upper of gridview. Please give me a solution..

```
return new Container(
  child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        child: new Image.asset(
          "assets/promo.png",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      new Container(
        child: new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
          controller: new ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: new List<Widget>.generate(16, (index) {
            return new GridTile(
                header: new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: new Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_cart,
                    size: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                child: new MyList(
                  nomor: '$index',
                ));
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

and this is the result:
[Flutter Gridview in Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLjvz.png)

Answer (score 149):

You just need to put your grid view into `Expanded` widget, for example:

```dart
body: new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Expanded(
      child: GridView.count(
        // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
        // horizontal, this would produce 2 rows.
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        // Generate 100 Widgets that display their index in the List
        children: List.generate(10, (index) {
          return _buildCard(index);
        }),
      ),
    ),
    new Text("text")
  ],
),
```

Comment: This only works when the `GridView` is the first item of `Column`. To make the GridView fit into any where in the column, remove the `Expanded` wrapper and add `shrinkWrap: true` property in `Gridview.count`

Answer (score 130):

**Reason for the error:**

`Column` expands to the maximum size in main axis direction (vertical axis), and so does the `GridView` (scroll direction is vertical by default)

**Solution**

You need to constrain the height of the `GridView`, so that it expands to fill the remaining space inside `Column`, there are several ways of solving this issue, use whichever suits you better.

---

1. If you want to allow `GridView` to take up all remaining space inside `Column` use `Flexible`.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Flexible(
         child: GridView(...),
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

---

2. If you want to limit your `GridView` to certain `height`, you can use `SizedBox`.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(
         height: 200, // constrain height
         child: GridView(...),
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

---

3. If your `GridView` is small, you may try `shrinkWrap` property on it.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       GridView(
         shrinkWrap: true, // use it
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

Comment: Great answer. Covers more cases than the currently accepted one.

Comment: I have put Gridview inside Expanded widget but it is still not working!!

Comment: How can I give a dynamic width to a child in gridview (horizontal direction) inside the column widget? My gridview child items are shrinked (Only the image is shown). If I give childAspectRatio it works but the width is static instead of a dynamic width.

Comment: @VinothVino That's not possible as of today, you need to use third party library, like staggered_grid_view.

Comment: upvote, The reason understanding the problem is much more important than just final solution

Answer (score 46):

If Column is the parent of `GridView` then it will give rendering issue as
It happens because `Column` and `GridView` both take the entire space of the screen individually which is there default behavior(Default axis of scrolling is Vertical).

**Solution:**

To solve the above problem we have to disable scrolling of `GridView`, This can be possible by shrinkWrap and physics property

**shrinkWrap:true** - With this `GridView` only occupies the space it needs

**physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()** - It disables scrolling functionality of `GridView`, which means now we have only `SingleChildScrollView` who provide the scrolling functionality.

**Code:**

```
SingleChildScrollView
   Column
        GridView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                //...
                )
```

Answer (score 18):

The answer mentioned by @RuslanLeshchenko is correct but if it is still not working for you, trying the following properties on GridView

1. Try changing `shrinkwrap` to true
2. Apply  `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()`

Comment: Worked for me. I set this property to my GridView.
I have Column and first two children are two image and 3rd one is GridView with 10 items. So the complete Column height is more than the Device height. When we scroll the grid i could not see all items.
Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You can solve it by these two properties and change them as follows :

```
shrinkWrap: true,
primary: false,
```

- **shrinkWrap** will wrap your and will handle overflow.
- Through **primary** we can set either you want to make this list scrollable or it's parent list. By setting it to false it allows to take scroll of parent list or scrollable view.

**NOTE** : You can also wrap your column with **SingleChildScrollView** to have scroll in your view.

Happy Fluttering !

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap with scaffold and scrollview

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
            children: [ 
          ...
```

Tested working on dialog model aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't fix.
Then again I used a GridView.builder().

I changed it to GridView.count and added shrinkWrap: true and physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() as mentioned in the other comments.

It works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `childAspectRatio` property of GridView to 0.8 or lower.

Answer (score -2):

```
body:Container(
   body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Exemple'),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                    children: <Widget>[
                          //Widgets
                    ]
               )
             )
           ]
         )
       )
```

Answer (score -2):

Just wrap `GridView` inside `ListView`

```dart
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
                GridView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                ),
            ],
        ),
)
```

Also it works with `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                    GridView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
    )
)
```

Works like a charm (: