# GridView containing Cards are getting Trimmed at the end in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-gridview

I am trying to create one Grid View page with Cards as list elements and the last of the cards are getting cut from the bottom. The following are relevant code snippets:

**createListBody.dart**

```
List<String> services = [
    
    'Demo1',
    'Demo2',
    'Demo3',
    'Demo4',
    'Demo5',
    'Demo6',
    'Demo7',
    'Demo8',
    'Demo9',
    'Demo10',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        children: services.map((String serviceName){
          return Container(
            child:Card(
              color: Colors.grey[500],
              elevation: 15,
              semanticContainer: true,
              shadowColor: palletFuchsia,
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  print("Tapped "+serviceName);
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    serviceName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**listScreen.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: palletWhiteDrawer,
      drawer: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          canvasColor: palletYellowDrawer,
        ),
        child: CreatDrawerWidget(),
      ),
      appBar: CreateAppBar(),
      body:GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ServiceListBody()
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

**Screenshot**
[image: As visible in the screenshot, the last card elements are getting cut, i.e. not getting rendered completely]

I am completely new to flutter so, sorry if there is some silly mistake. But any help would be useful.
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for exploring, you can do `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *2,` It shouldn't get cut anymore right?

### Solution 1

Your telling your container a given height which is fix for the moment, no matter how many items you got inside your `ListView`.

You can for example use `ConstrainedBox` with `shrinkWrap:true` and manage your max height

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200, minHeight: 56.0),
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    ...
```

more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html

---

### Solution 2

use `Slivers`, they are dynamic.

For this you need to customize your structure a little bit. You wrap everything with a `CustomScrollView()`, `SliverToBoxAdapter()` for fixed elements and `SliverList()` for dynamic ones, makes it work like a charm.

Example using `CustomScrollView` and `SliverToBoxAdapter`:

```
return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          // Place sliver widgets here
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 30, 25, 20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 299,
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                        ...
```

You can define the height with the `SizedBox` `height`. Also you can apply nice effects to your whole View on the `CustomScrollView`

Example Sliverlist:

```
   SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (ctx, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: list[index],
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {}),
        childCount: list.length,
  )),
```

Infos about slivers: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/explore-slivers-in-flutter-d44073bffdf6

Comment: Thank you so much, will try these solutions out and will comment the results! :)

Comment: Yea sure youre welcome :) If it helped you make sure to vote as accepted answer

Comment: making ```height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*2``` stops the scrolling completely, and the lower cards are not rendered at all

Comment: Yea could be because of the rendering errors. By the way I see you used the Gridview. Make sure to use the SliverGrid for perfect solution :-) Check this out: https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f You can see in the examples every height is dynamic and scrollable

Answer (score 1):

The `GridView` Widget itself is `Scrollable` , So you don't have to wrap it with a `Column` and `SingleChildScrollView` Widget...
You can now simply scroll down if the Circles goes out of the screen

If you wish all the circles to fit in the screen.. You'll have to use

`var mobileHeight =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

And then the height of each circles will be `mobileHeight` divided by the no. of circles vertically.

Comment: Yes, if using only ```GridView``` Widget, the page is working just fine, but I want to add one ```Container``` with some text above the ```GridView```, that's why wrapped it in the Column widget

Comment: @AmitDubey Then you could try wrapping the `GridView` with `Expanded` and then you can safely wrap it with a `Column` widget. It it gives an error there are other ways to do it... You can look it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943272/flutter-gridview-in-column-whats-solution/51167158)

Answer (score 0):

On `GridView` add:

```
shrinkWrap: true

physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics()
```