# RenderFlex overflow using Flutter GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, dynamic, overflow

I used a GridView.count() to display dynamic data in my app, but each of my GridView elements doesn't fully display.

Here is what it looks like :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
Column(
      children: [
        buildSubheadingText('Mes projets'),
        buildVerticalSpace(5.0),
        GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: ContextManager.projects.map((value) {
              return ProjectCard(project: value);
            }).toList()
        )
      ],
    );
```

I have added the attributes shrinkWrap at true and physics at BouncingScrollPhysics or NeverScrollableScrollPhysics as advised in the answers of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943272/flutter-gridview-in-column-whats-solution/51167158) but as you can see it doesn't work for me.

Also, I don't want to use a fixed height because data is dynamic here.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set custom height for grid using childAspectRatio attribute

Example:-

```
Column(
      children: [
        buildSubheadingText('Mes projets'),
        buildVerticalSpace(5.0),
        GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          childAspectRatio: 2/3, //gives custom height to your grid element
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: ContextManager.projects.map((value) {
              return ProjectCard(project: value);
            }).toList()
        )
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

`GridView` children's size depends on  `childAspectRatio`, default it is `1.0`, you can increase height by changing default `childAspectRatio`. like

```dart
  child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.2, //width /height
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using this library,
[staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).