# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget Error Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to display grid view, but I got an error saying "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget".

Here is my code:

```
 body: Container {
    ...
    child: Column {
       children : [
          Container {
             child: GridView(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                   crossAxisCount: 4,
                ),
                children: [
                   CircleAvatar(
                      child: Icon(
                         Icons.person,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      child: Icon(
                         Icons.person,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      child: Icon(
                         Icons.person,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                ]
             )
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

And here is the error:

- Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
- Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
- RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#8c1a9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
  Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Gridview in Column. What's solution..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943272/flutter-gridview-in-column-whats-solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `GridView` provide `shrinkWrap: true,`. This is also discussed [Flutter Gridview in Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49943272/10157127).

```dart
child: GridView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  gridDelegate:
```

Comment: but I can't resize the circleavatar, tried using size and radius but I got an error saying "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."

Comment: `GridView` children's size depends on  `childAspectRatio`,  can be found inside `gridDelegate`

Comment: ah I see, thank you

Comment: For your case, you might be looking for `Wrap`

Comment: shrinkWrap is bad for performance if there are large number of items in the list. You can refer this https://youtu.be/LUqDNnv_dh0

Comment: Yes I prefer `slivers` but for this i don't see any issue, can you share expanded vs shrink

Answer (score 0):

You used GridView inside Column that is why flutter is giving error. Try wrapping GridView with Expanded or Flexible widget

```
Column(
     children: Expanded(
        child: GridView(...)
    )
)
```